# Nvidia drivers for an HP dv6000 laptop running CentOS 6.9?

Tags: centos, nvidia, suspend

I'm having an issue with waking up my laptop from *Suspension* -- the screen lights up but remains black and I can't log back into the OS! This happens if I actively press the power button and choose to Suspend. If instead I go away from the laptop, the screen goes off after some time. When I come back and say, move the touch-pad I'm prompted to type my user and password with the typical GNOME screen.

I've faced this problem with previous Linux distros but can't remember how I fixed it. I'm guessing it was installing Nvidia drivers that did the magick, I'm not sure. Has anyone had a similar problem? How did you fix it? I know one can "suspend to RAM" or "suspend to disk" -- how/where do you set that?

Here are my *hardware specs*:

**lsb_release -a**

```
  LSB Version:    :base-4.0-ia32:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-ia32:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-ia32:printing-4.0-noarch
    Distributor ID: CentOS
    Description:    CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
    Release:        6.9
    Codename:       Final
```

**lspci | grep VGA**

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G72M [GeForce Go 7400] (rev a1)
```

**lscpu -a**

```
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 15
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU         T5600  @ 1.83GHz
Stepping:              6
CPU MHz:               1833.000
BogoMIPS:              3658.85
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              2048K
```

Answer (score 0):

Head off to Nvidia's website and download scripts for your PC.

Then find dkms package for your distro (.deb or .rpm).

Follow the instructions in this link: [url](https://pyrx.sourceforge.io/blog/103-installing-nvidia-driver-on-centos-6)